# I'm trying to import an excel file to SQL via visual Studio. How do I make it read the data starting from the second row?

Tags: c#, sql, excel, visual-studio, linq

I'm trying to import an excel file to SQL server via visual Studio. How do I make it read the data starting from the second row and not the first row of the excel file? My code works perfectly as it is, but I want it to start reading the data from the 2nd row. Here is my code:

```
using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    using ExcelDataReader;

    namespace ImportDB2
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {


            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                OpenFileDialog ope = new OpenFileDialog();
                ope.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm";
                if (ope.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                    return;

                FileStream stream = new FileStream(ope.FileName, FileMode.Open);
                IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();


                DataClasses1DataContext conn = new DataClasses1DataContext();



                foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
                {

                    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
                    {


                        Employee addtable = new Employee()
                        {

                            Serial = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
                            Name = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
                            Class = Convert.ToString(dr[2]),
                            Department = Convert.ToString(dr[3]),
                            Status = Convert.ToString(dr[4]),
                            Position = Convert.ToString(dr[5]),
                            Email = Convert.ToString(dr[6])
                        };
                        conn.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(addtable);
                    }
                }
                conn.SubmitChanges();
                excelReader.Close();
                stream.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("YEEESSSS FINALLY");
            }
        }
    }
```

What line of code should I put for it to start reading on the second row, and where inside my code should I put it in? Hope someone can help, thank you. ^_^

Comment: hint: In your second loop, instead of using foreach why not use a for loop and use the counter to start at the second row? or am I missing something?

Comment: `My code works perfectly as it is`  No, it is leaking in at least 2 places

Comment: Do you know which lines are relevant for handling rows in the snippet?

Comment: Use SSIS to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool skip = true;
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    if(skip) 
    {
        skip = false;
        continue;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to skip a row in your `for` loop for each table, do this:

```
foreach (DataTable table in result.Tables)
{
    bool skippedRow = false;
    foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
    {
        if (!skippedRow)
        {
            skippedRow = true;
            continue;
        }
        Employee addtable = new Employee()
        {
            Serial = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]),
            Name = Convert.ToString(dr[1]),
            Class = Convert.ToString(dr[2]),
            Department = Convert.ToString(dr[3]),
            Status = Convert.ToString(dr[4]),
            Position = Convert.ToString(dr[5]),
            Email = Convert.ToString(dr[6])
        };
        conn.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(addtable);
    }
}
```